# Where use 'to' and 'for'

Tags: prepositions, usage

I have a sentence about a function description (in a program's code) :

> Redirect to action to return the file to user.

How do I properly use *to* and *for*?

Here's my description of the situation:

I have a user, and I redirect this user to an action.  The action generates a file and returns it to that user's web browser.

I think it is better to say the following:

> Redirect to action WHICH return the file FOR user

What do you think?

Comment: You might like our sister site: [ell.se].

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to ELL!  This question was somewhat hard to understand, so I did my best to edit it into standard English.  Could you please take a look and tell me if I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @snailboat I still can't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I properly use *to* and *for*?

In the most literal sense, to means "in the direction of" and for means "on behalf of".  So,

```
I'll deliver the box to you tomorrow.
```

means that you will receive the box.  However,

```
I'll deliver the box for you tomorrow.
```

means that I will take the box from you and bring it to someone else (on your behalf) tomorrow.

The difference between to and for is usually less dramatic than this:

```
I brought cookies to the kids.  I brought cookies for the kids.
```

have roughly the same meaning, because you are really bringing the cookies both in the direction of the kids and on their behalf.  There are also numerous idiomatic uses.  For example "Come for me at six" means "Pick me up at six," and "Come to me at six" means (roughly) "Visit me at six."

I should also point out that "for" has many other meanings in contexts where substituting "to" would not make a correct sentence, e. g. "I am waiting for the train; this present is for you; we live for excitement."  My comments are strictly confined to situations where either to or for would make a correct sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, either "to" or "for" is correct.  Is this a comment in the code for a program?  As far as code is concerned, it's more common to use "to" in this situation.  While the file is "for" the end user, you're sending it "to" him/her.  As a programmer myself, I would say something like this in a comment:

> Redirect to action that returns the file to user

If you're writing a complete sentence (in documentation, for example), I'd say something like this:

> Redirect to an action that returns the file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would understand this

> Redirect to the action which will return a file to the browser